# Zariski closure and affine transformations commute

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field, $X\subseteq \mathbb K^n$ a subset, and $\ f:\mathbb K^n\rightarrow \mathbb K^m$ an affine map. Using the standard notation $V$, $I$ for algebraic geometry, it should hold that
$$V(I(f(X)))=f(V(I(X))),$$
i.e. that the Zariski closure $VI$ commutes with the affine transformation $f$. Why is that?

(To specify the notation more: for a set $Y$, we mean by $I(Y)$ the set of all polynomials vanishing on $Y$; and for a set of polynomials $J$, we mean by $V(J)$ the set of all zeros common to all polynomials in $J$.)

Note that I do NOT assume $f$ to be bijective, and that $X$ does not need to be an algebraic set.

The equality obviously doesn't hold for every polynomial mapping $\ f$, as that would mean that an image of Zariski closed set under polynomial mapping is always Zariski closed, which is not true (e.g. $f(x)=x^2:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $X=\mathbb R$).

EDIT:
As pointed out by reuns, using the general topology fact that $\overline{f(X)}\supseteq f(\overline{X})$ for continuous maps, it is enough to show that $f(V(I(X)))$ is Zariski closed (i.e. an algebraic set).

Comment: The reformulation of the question would be "if $f$ is $\textbf{affine}$ then $\overline{f(X)}=f(\overline{X})$".
The equality does not hold for $f$ continuous in general, as my example shows. If $f(x)=x^2$, we have $\overline{f(R)}=\overline{[0,\inf)}=R \neq [0,\inf)=f(R)=f(\overline{R})$.
But you are right that $\supseteq$ holds in general, so that shows one direction.

Comment: In what sense is $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \to x^2$ continuous, is it continuous for the topology induced by $V(I(X))$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is a polynomial map, and polynomial maps are continuous w.r.t. Zariski topology.

Comment: $\overline{f(X)} = f(\overline{X})$ is true whenever $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets (that's part of your definition of affine right ?). Here you are saying $f^{-1}(U)$ is open whenever $U$ is open (this would make $f$ continuous) but $f(X)$ isn't closed whenever $X$ ? Isn't the situation different for polynomial maps $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Indeed, that is the case. I am not sure whether the situation is different for algebraically closed fields.

Comment: For $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ a polynomial the situation is different because the only closed sets are finite sets plus $\mathbb{C}$, the only open sets are their complementary. For the finite sets and their complementary there is no problems, as $f(\mathbb{C}) =\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This is the same for $\mathbb{R}$ though. In $\mathbb{R}$, the only closed sets are also finite sets, and, on the other hand, every finite set is closed, as you can interpolate any finite set by a polynomial of high enough degree. My particular counter-example with $x\mapsto x^2$ would not work in $\mathbb{C}$, but I am not sure whether an image of Zariski closed set via continuous map would necessarily be closed, when we are over algebraically closed field. I would think it's not.

Comment: For $f:K^n \to K^m$ a polynomial map, composing $x \mapsto (x,f(x))$ and $(x,y) \mapsto y$, the former works well over any field, the latter works well if $K$ is algebraically closed or finite. If $K$ is not algebraically closed nor finite then there is an irreducible polynomial $p$ and $p(K)$ is not closed since it is infinite but not the whole of $K$.